# Pandas Groupby Conditional Filtering

Tags: python, python-3.x, filtering, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

I have a large dataframe similar to below.  I want to Groupby 'account', having the Groupby keep only those groups, where there is a "grade" among the group (at least one record within that "account" group has a "grade" more than 0).
In this example after grouping by "account", there should only be four groups remaining (1,3,4,5).

How can I do this in Pandas?

```
store = {'account': ['1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    'sales': [150, 200, 50,100, 125, 250, 300 ],
    'employees': [3, 5, 1,2, 3,5,7 ],
    'grade': [80, 90, '','' ,75, 60,85]}
df = pd.DataFrame(store)
df.groupby(['account'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want [`DataFrameGroupBy.filter`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html), which in your case would boil down to

```
df.groupby('account').filter(lambda x: any(x.grade))
```

For instance (where I modified your input a bit to cover some of the edge cases):

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]:
  account  employees grade  sales
0       1          3    80    150
1       1          5          200
2       2          1           50
3       2          2    60    100
4       3          3          125
5       4          5    60    250
6       5          7    85    300

In [15]: df.groupby('account').filter(lambda x: any(x.grade))
Out[15]:
  account  employees grade  sales
0       1          3    80    150
1       1          5          200
2       2          1           50
3       2          2    60    100
5       4          5    60    250
6       5          7    85    300
```

Comment: Great, works.  I'm still new to this, is "filtering"  **contextual**?  For example in this Groupby, the default is a search "within" the groups, and x.grade is looking through all the "grade" for the group?

Comment: Yes, up to one technical detail: `any` will short-circuit and return `True` the moment it encounters a non-empty grade, so it that sense you don't necessarily look through all of them.

Comment: To picture what's going on, you could `def f(x): print(x); return any(x.grade)` and instead do `df.groupby('account').filter(f)`; this way you'll see how the predicate ends up being applied to each group.